# expected value of the product of two independent variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a couple of random variables with conjunct density
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)= 2\frac{y}{(1+x)^2}$$ for $0<y< 1$ and $x>0$.

I have to determine the expected value of the product of $X$ and $Y$.

$$E[XY]= \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \int_{x=0}^{x= \infty} 2\frac{xy^2}{(1+x)^2} dxdy= \int_{y=0}^{y=1} 2y^2  dy\int_{x=0}^{x= \infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^2} dx$$

I'm trying to solve the integral with $x$ in this way:
$$\int_{t=1}^{t= \infty} \frac{t-1}{t^2} dx= \left[\log t+ \frac{1}{t} \right]_{t=1}^{t= \infty}= \infty$$

Am I right or am I making mistakes?

Comment: Is $0<y<1$? If not, the limits on the original integral aren't correct.

Comment: @B.Mehta Sorry, I edited the text

Comment: I think that you're correct.

Comment: Indeed, $X$ and $Y$ are almost suely nonnegative, $E(Y)=\frac23$ and $E(X)=+\infty$, hence $E(XY)=+\infty$.

Comment: @Did the marginal density $f_X(x)= \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ while the marginal density $f_Y(y)= 2y$ and X and Y are independent

Comment: @Did $E[X]=1 $ and $E[Y]=1 $ ...I can't understand

Comment: Why do you think $E(X)=1$?

Comment: @Did Sorry, I'm a bit tired. I was forgetting x and y in the integrals